# What's the name of the pamphlet in company with Introduction to Calculus and Analysis by Richard Courant?

Tags: calculus, reference-request

In the preface of *Introduction to calculus and Analysis I* written by Richard Courant, the author said that

> Numerous examples and problems are given at the end of various chapters. Some are challenging, some are even difficult; most of them supplement the material in the text. In an additional **pamphlet** more problems and exercises of a routine character will be collected, and moreover, answers or hints for the solutions will be given.

Have you seen this pamphlet? What's the name of this pamphlet or where can I get it?

Comment: [tag:reference-request] should not be used as a standalone tag; see [tag-wiki](http://math.stackexchange.com/tags/reference-request/info) and [meta](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/2498/the-meta-tags).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The book you're asking about is:

Albert Abraham Blank, [**Problems in Calculus and Analysis**](https://archive.org/details/ProblemsInCalculusAndAnalysisAlbertBlank), 1966, x + 264 pages.

See: [WorldCat listing](http://www.worldcat.org/title/problems-in-calculus-and-analysis/oclc/636646777) and [google-books listing](http://books.google.com/books/about/Problems_in_Calculus_and_Analysis.html?id=u-DTMgEACAAJ) and [AbeBooks listing](http://www.abebooks.com/9780471079507/Problems-Calculus-Analysis-Blank-0471079502/plp)

For reviews in English, see: **[1]** Santi Kumar Chatterjea, [Zbl 135.26805](https://zbmath.org/?q=an%3A0135.25803) and **[2]** John Wainwright Hesselgreaves, **Mathematical Gazette** 51 #376 (May 1967), p. 165. [JSTOR](https://www.jstor.org/stable/3614415)

For a review in Russian, see: [L. Tclaf, **Zh. Vychisl. Mat. Mat. Fiz.** 6:6 (1966), pp. 1142–1143](http://www.mathnet.ru/php/archive.phtml?wshow=paper&jrnid=zvmmf&paperid=8996&option_lang=eng).

For a review in Norwegian, see Olav Njåstad, **Nordisk Matematisk Tidskrift** 14 #3-4 (1966), pp. 116-117. [JSTOR](https://www.jstor.org/stable/24524772)